# Selectively Fread based on the results from data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a folder full of csv files with certain naming pattern (all with 4 digits), "0001.csv", "0002.csv" etc. All the files have same headings and format.

If I want to combine the ALL the files or do analysis with them. I can do this

```
all.files <- list.files(path = "/Users",pattern = ".csv")
DT <- lapply(all.files, fread # or other self-defined function)
DT <- rbindlist(DT)
```

BUT now I want to do the `list.files`based on certain output from one `data.table`.

```
dt <- data.table(Ticker = c("0001","0002","0003","0004"), Status = c("True", "True","True","False"))
```

```
> dt
   Ticker Status
1:   0001   True
2:   0002   True
3:   0003   True
4:   0004  False
```

I want to combine the files whose `status` is `TRUE` in `dt`. Not all. so `list.files` may not be applicable.

Any suggestions? thanks a lot.

Comment: If the names of the files are contained in `dt$Ticker`, then maybe just use `all.files <- paste0(dt[as.logical(Status), Ticker], ".csv")`.

Answer (score 2):

If I get it correctly this can be done as:

```
DT <- lapply(paste0(dt[Status == 'True', Ticker], '.csv'), function(x) fread(x))
DT <- rbindlist(DT)
```